# Getting attachment contents (files) with contents using EWS Request

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

Trying to get the attachment contents (files) against mail item in outlook web add-in (Office 365) using the EWS request as instructed in the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-get-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Successfully got the attachment ids, but while passing those attachment ids to the GetAttachment request envelope, it fails and returns the following response:
{"value":null,"status":"failed","error":{"name":"GenericResponseError","message":"**The requested web method is unavailable to this caller or application.**","code":**9020**}}

```
function getAttachmentsByAttachmentId(attachmentId){
var requestEnvelopStr = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
requestEnvelopStr += '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">';
requestEnvelopStr += '<soap:Header>';
requestEnvelopStr += '<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010" />';
requestEnvelopStr += '</soap:Header>';
requestEnvelopStr += '<soap:Body>';
requestEnvelopStr += '<m:GetAttachment>';
requestEnvelopStr += '<m:AttachmentIds>';
requestEnvelopStr += '<t:AttachmentId Id="' + attachmentId+'" />';
requestEnvelopStr += '</m:AttachmentIds>';
requestEnvelopStr += '</m:GetAttachment>';
requestEnvelopStr += '</soap:Body>';
requestEnvelopStr += '</soap:Envelope>';
console.log("Before Calling EWS...");
//Calling EWS

Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(requestEnvelopStr, attachmentsCallBack);
}

function attachmentsCallBack(asyncResultAttachments) {
console.log("asyncResultAttachments.value = " + JSON.stringify(asyncResultAttachments));
}
```

Comment: Does your attachmentId need some escaping?  You can also check out Fiddler while doing this request, which should capture the request that the Outlook API is doing under the covers, and review the request format, and the response headers/body.  Sometimes additional error information is available in the response headers.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Getting attachment contents is not supported by addins through EWS. A supported list of APIs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/web-services#ews-operations-that-add-ins-support). A potential solution would be to use one of our preview API's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.attachmentcontent?view=outlook-js-preview). Keep in mind that since the API is in preview it may be prone to bugs until it's released as part of a requirement set. Another solution could be to have your backend make the call to retrieve the attachment content.

Comment: We were fetching attachment content from backend by sending `attachmentToken` , `ewsUrl` and all required fields from our addin to backend. For some reason we are now getting JSON response without attachment content. 

Can you please guide w.r.t this issue.

Comment: This sounds like a new question, could you please create a new post with more details on the request your backend is making and the response you are getting?

Comment: hi hi. Sorry it was a bug created by my team mate. All good. Thanks for your reply.